# Can we use "burst" as an adjective?

Tags: meaning

Can we use a word "burst" as an adjective? If not, which word can we use instead of this word?

For example is it correct to say:

> I had a "burst" (adj) pipe in my room.

Comment: See [this meta discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and provide us with a complete sentence in which you wish to use that word.

Comment: I saw this word in a sentence from the book I am reading at the moment.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  Please provide more context if you want to know more.

Comment: I had a "burst'(adj) pipe in my room-is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

The past participle of the verb 'burst', is also 'burst', so you could see something like 'my balloon is burst', or "I needed a plumber when I had a burst pipe' where the participle is used as an adjective. Other participles which might be applied, as adjectives, to a pipe, might be buried, painted, curved, broken, hidden, etc.